# Criteria question with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

I'm trying to use NHibernate for data access, and I have 2 simple entities that look like this:

```
public class User : IEntity
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public string Logon { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

   public bool IsNew
   {
      get { return (ID == 0) ? true : false; }
   }

   public User()
   {
      Roles = new List<Role>();
   }
}

public class Role : IEntity
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string RoleName { get; set; }
   public string RoleDescription { get; set; }

   public bool IsNew
   {
      get { return (ID == 0) ? true : false; }
   }
}
```

My question......how do I construct a Criteria if I want to find any user that contains a Role with an ID of 1 in it's Roles collection?

Comment: for the class Role why do you have RoleName and Description instead of just Name & Description?

Also you can stuff IsNew into a base class.

Comment: What do you keep with the IEntity Interface ? This is another question but could you please asnwer. I like to learn techniques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, this ended up being relatively straight forward to do:

```
// role was the role passed in to my Find method.
var criteria = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof (User))
            .CreateCriteria("Roles")
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ID", role.ID));
```